GET https://allisonnoda.com/assets/index-BLXWdqdL.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto de React, la web en local host, se ve perfecta, la subí a netlify, que es un host gratuito carga perfecto, ahora cuando lo coloco en un hosting pago DonWeb con sistema linux, la web no funciona y arroja error.Paso el codigo y fotos. Espero que me puedan ayudar. Si necesitan que suba mas informacion me avisan. Muchas Gracias Matias.





<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Allison Noda</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-BLXWdqdL.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/index-DGRFN7cV.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>




Hola Matias, el error 404 indica que el archivo no se encuentra en la ruta indicada. La pregunta es ¿que subiste al directorio public_html? Por lo que veo, todo lo que está en el directorio local dist debería estar en public_html

No, ahi vos lo ves en dist porque te pase el código desde visual Code, pero si subi todo al public_html. Lo que subi es todo lo que está dentro de la carpeta dist, no la carpeta directa porque donWeb no lo toma con la carpeta dist.

Que pasa si editas el path? agregando un ./ o poniendo el path directo?
